# Questions on Intersections and Differences

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was wondering whether $(A-B)\cap C=(A\cap C)-(B\cap C)$. In a Venn diagram, it seems to be true but I didn't know if there was a special case for which this is not equivalent. Thank you! (Here I am using - instead of \ for set differences as a note on my notation)

Comment: There are two distinct  (pedantic) industrial strength approaches to such questions: [1] Similar to a truth table, represent via a chart, the $(2^3)$ possibilities, re an element either is or is not in each of sets $A,B,C$.  Then, see if all $8$ possibilities match, for the the LHS and RHS expressions in your question. [2] Set $S =$ set $T \iff S \subseteq T$ and $T \subseteq S$.  So, try proving that if an element is in the LHS set, then it has to be in the RHS set, and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this approach!

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
(A\cap C)-(B\cap C)&=(A\cap C)\cap(B\cap C)^c\\
&=(A\cap C)\cap (B^c\cup C^c)\\
&=(A\cap C\cap B^c)\cup(A\cap C\cap C^c)\\
&=(A\cap B^c\cap C)\cup\emptyset\\
&=(A-B)\cap C
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Taking an universal set (for example, $A\cup B\cup C$), we have
$$(A\setminus B)\cap C=A\cap\bar B\cap\ C$$
And
$$(A\cap C)\setminus(B\cap C)=(A\cap C)\cap\overline{B\cap C}=(A\cap C)\cap(\bar B\cup\bar C)=(A\cap C\cap\bar B)\cup(A\cap C\cap\bar C)$$
Since the second term of the union is empty, both set are the same.